# android GCM registration id blank

Tags: registration, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to do push notification in android using GCM. I read the Google docs for GCM and there demo application. i include gcm,jar in lib.bur regid variable is black show in log.i thing some error in my code please check my code and tell me appropriate solution .

```
package avi.android.pushnotifications;

import static avi.android.pushnotifications.CommonUtilities.DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION;
import static avi.android.pushnotifications.CommonUtilities.EXTRA_MESSAGE;
import static avi.android.pushnotifications.CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID;
import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.IntentFilter;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.widget.TextView;
  import android.widget.Toast;
 import com.androidhive.pushnotifications.R;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
// label to display gcm messages
TextView lblMessage;
final static String Tag =MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
// Asyntask
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mRegisterTask;

// Alert dialog manager
AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

// Connection detector
ConnectionDetector cd;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

    // Check if Internet present
    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        // Internet Connection is not present
        alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this,
                "Internet Connection Error",
                "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }



    // Make sure the device has the proper dependencies.
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);

    // Make sure the manifest was properly set - comment out this line
    // while developing the app, then uncomment it when it's ready.
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

    lblMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblMessage);

    registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));

    // Get GCM registration id
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    Log.v(Tag, "Registered regId"+regId);
    // Check if regid already presents
    if (regId.equals("")) {
        // Registration is not present, register now with GCM           
        GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
        Log.v(Tag, "Registered");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " registered with GCM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //sachin...................

        final Context context = this;
        mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // Register on our server
                // On server creates a new user
                ServerUtilities.register(context, regId);
                //ServerUtilities.unregister(context, regId);
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                mRegisterTask = null;
            }

        };
        mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);

        //.................................sachin

    } else {
        // Device is already registered on GCM
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {
            // Skips registration.              
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already registered with GCM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
            // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
            // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.
            final Context context = this;
            mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    // Register on our server
                    // On server creates a new user
                    //ServerUtilities.register(context, regId);
                    ServerUtilities.unregister(context, regId);
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    mRegisterTask = null;
                }

            };
            mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
        }
    }
}       

/**
 * Receiving push messages
 * */
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
        WakeLocker.acquire(getApplicationContext());

        /**
         * Take appropriate action on this message
         * depending upon your app requirement
         * For now i am just displaying it on the screen
         * */

        // Showing received message
        lblMessage.append(newMessage + "\n");           
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Message: " + newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Releasing wake lock
        WakeLocker.release();
    }
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (mRegisterTask != null) {
        mRegisterTask.cancel(true);
    }
    try {
        unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);
        GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("UnRegister Receiver Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

   }
```

> logcat

```
03-04 06:25:03.723: V/MainActivity(2206): Registered regId
03-04 06:25:03.723: D/GCMRegistrar(2206): resetting backoff for    
com.androidhive.pushnotifications
03-04 06:25:03.733: V/GCMRegistrar(2206): Registering app   
com.androidhive.pushnotifications of senders 1099113278913
03-04 06:25:03.773: V/MainActivity(2206): Registered
03-04 06:25:04.003: D/dalvikvm(2206): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 216K, 10% free 2996K/3300K,   
paused 75ms, total 84ms
03-04 06:25:04.083: I/AndroidHive GCM(2206): registering device (regId = )
03-04 06:25:04.083: D/AndroidHive GCM(2206): Attempt #1 to register
03-04 06:25:04.163: V/AndroidHive GCM(2206): Posting 
'email=sa@gmail.com&regId=&name=sa' to 
http://www.xyx.com/xxx/sac_images/newu.php
03-04 06:25:04.193: E/URL(2206): > http://www.xyx.com/xxx/sac_images/newu.php
03-04 06:25:04.193: W/EGL_emulation(2206): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-04 06:25:09.513: V/GCMRegistrar(2206): Setting registeredOnServer status as true    
until 2014-03-11 07:25:09.509
03-04 06:25:10.143: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(2206): onReceive:   
com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
 03-04 06:25:10.143: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(2206): GCM IntentService class: 
com.androidhive.pushnotifications.GCMIntentService
03-04 06:25:10.163: V/GCMBaseIntentService(2206): Acquiring wakelock
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the deprecated gcm libraries. Now gcm is part of google play services. Please refer [gcm](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) and use the latest libraries and API